# Delay opening contextmenu

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I want to show `contextmenu` of the element (as when right mouse button is pressed) after 1 s delay. What I did so far:

1) Tried to delay the execution of the callback with promises - doesn't work, `contextmenu` is shown asynchronously and irrelevant of the callback execution.

```js
p.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {  // contextmenu is shown instantly
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
  .then(() => console.log('1 s passed'))  // shown in 1 s
})
```

```html
<p id="p">Hello</p>
```

2) Dispatched `new Event` myself - no `contextmenu` at all in this case

```
enter code here
```

```js
p.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  const contextmenu = new MouseEvent('contextmenu')
 setTimeout(() => p.dispatchEvent(contextmenu), 1000) 
})

p.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {
 console.log('contextmenu event arrived')  // message is shown in 1 s but no contextmenu
})
```

```html
<p id="p">Hello</p>
```

Comment: The contextmenu event is for browser, I suggest not to interfere it. What is your root problem? Maybe we can think of a work around.

Comment: I wanted to simulate the kind of behavior that Total Commander (file manages) has. That is when you right click the element it gets selected, if you hold and move the mouse - more elements get selected. But if you right click and hold over one element - the context menu gets open in a second. I guess, the workaround can be completely new custom context menu (div) appearing when I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out (https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html). One of a tool to implement the context menu. With this, you have fully control of the context menu behavior.

Comment: So, the custom menu in the end. Good enough for me. Thank you.